# Conditional Formatting blanks if cell in another column is NOT blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet with Columns `A-Y`.

Column `A` is a prefilled set of numbers 1-200
`B-Y` are filled in by the end-user.
I am trying to highlight the empty cells based on Column `B`.

For example, the end-user enters the **Date in Column `B`** but does not complete the rest of the row, it would **highlight each cell that is blank**.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following formula

```
=NOT(ISBLANK($B3))*ISBLANK(B3)
```

[image]

***(do adjust ranges and locale syntax to meet your needs)***